# Python Qualtrics Data

Tags: python, qualtrics

So, I am pulling data from the Qualtrics v3 API, and would like to pull the data every night. How could I pull all of the data one night and come back the next night and pull all of the new data. There is a parameter that the survey responds with called "lastModified" which is the last modified date.

Here is an example call:
    import urllib.request #default module for Python 3.X

```
url = 'https://yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys'
header = {'X-API-TOKEN': ''}

req = urllib.request.Request(url,None,header) #generating the request object

handler = urllib.request.urlopen(req) #running the request object

print(handler.status) #print status code
print(handler.reason)
```

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
  "result": {
"elements": [
  {
    "id": "SV_0D54a3emdOh7bBH",
    "name": "Imported Survey",
    "ownerId": "UR_8CywXqaSNzzu1Bb",
    "lastModified": "2013-10-22T20:12:33Z",
    "isActive": true
  },
  ...
],
    "nextPage": "https://yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys?       offset=10"
  },
  "meta": {
    "httpStatus": "200 - OK"
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a great question, but my answer would be just do the thing you described... So query it each night and only query the new stuff. No idea what the JSON looks like, because you didn't post an example of the data, but it probably has a time stamp (Not sure if 'lastModified' works). Or you can check to see if you already have it --> for data in query: If data not in last_nights_data: ((write data to somewhere))

Comment: I am very sorry I updated it with the response, and the call.

Comment: No don't worry about it, thanks for uploading this stuff! Do you know the nature of 'lastModified'? Are things modified on different days than they're uploaded? If so you're going to have to use the second method I mentioned. So check new data against the old.

Comment: Well the problem I am having is that we do not currently have access to the API, but the check should be cleared very soon. So I do not have access to the actual data, and am writing basically some pseudocode so when we have access we can implement this instantly. So you're basically saying I should gather all of the data and store it on my local machine with the GET request I have. Then the next day do the same thing, but check it against the prior day's data and only take what is new. How would I even go about that? Thank you so much for this help.

Comment: No problem. And thats only if lastModified can change or is an indicator of when the actual survey was filled out, not when it was put into their DB or whatever. If thats the case new data can be added for a date three days ago and you wouldn't know it. To check against it I would write the 'id' field of every piece of data you have to a csv and when you query say --> for i in query: if i['id'] not in csv_of_old_ids: list.append(i)

Comment: Alright cool thank you so much. Have a great day!

Comment: No problem, you do likewise!

Comment: Sorry for this last question, but could I add this append query into the get request to make it all run in one shot?

Comment: For sure it would be like --> for i in urllib.request.urlopen(req): if i['id'] not in csv_of_old_ids: list.append(i) else: pass <-- Here I'm assuming that 'urllib.request.urlopen(req)' is the main query you make

Comment: Alright thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use responseexports instead surveys. Save the last response id retrieved each day. Then, you can use the lastResponseId parameter to specify where to start pulling the new data.

Comment: Are you familiar to the qualtrics responseexports? I would go about using it, but since I do not currently have the API enabled I cannot play around with it. Do you have any examples of this call?

Comment: Do you not think the above suggestion will not work?

Comment: I haven't gotten around to implementing responseexports in v3 yet.  I've implemented its equivalent in v2.5.  The suggestion above won't work because it is based off surveys.  That only gives you information about the surveys (ids, name, etc.); it doesn't return any response data.  Even if it did, the approach of comparing the data to figure out what is new is completely unnecessary since the responseexports call uses the  lastResponseId parameter.

Comment: BTW, on the Qualtrics site there is example Python code using responseexports but it is for exporting a csv instead of json.

Comment: could I not just do what he said above, but use the GET servey url: https://yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/:surveyId? I will use the response first, and try to just do both.

Comment: Using surveys with the surveyId is going to give you information about the survey (questions, blocks, etc.).  Unless you are editing your survey everyday it isn't going to change.  When you write "pulling data" I assume you want survey response data.  The only way to get survey response data with the v3 API is responseexports.

Comment: would I have any trouble using the lastResponseId if someone starts the survey, but does not finish it? Is the response stored in the response data once it is started, or once the survey is submitted?

Comment: A response isn't stored as a response until it is finished (submitted).  In progress responses are kept separate.

Comment: Hey, how did you parse your json that you got? Did you use python?

Comment: I use php.  I use curl to do the api call and json_decode to convert the json to an associative array.